# Sqlalchemy doesn't call model's reconstructor on object refresh

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model, which should convert some fields on initialization. I've tried to use `sqlalchemy.orm.reconstructor`, but faced a problem (or misundersanding) of model auto-refreshing.

This is example of my model:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor

t_model = db.Table(
    'models', 
    db.metadata,
    dbc.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    dbc.Column('value', db.String)
)


class Model(db.Model):

  __table__ = t_order_data

  def __init__(self, value)
      self.value = value

  @reconstructor
  def init_on_load(self)
      """cast to None if value is empty string"""
      self.value = None if not self.value else self.value

  def run_db_function(self)
      try:
          result = db.session.execute(db.func.somefunc('some_param')).fetchone()
      except Exception:
          db.session.rollback()
          raise
      else:
          db.session.commit()
          return result
```

What does my code do:

```
model = Model.query.get(1)  # in table this row is id=1, value=''
```

which begins implicit transaction and selects model data.

```
model.value  # returns None -- OK
```

Then i perform function

```
model.run_db_function()
```

which runs DB's routine and then commits transaction.

Then, when I try to access `value` attribute, sqlalchemy begins new implicit transaction, in which re-fetches this model again.

But this time value won't be converted

```
model.value  # returns '' -- NOT OK
```

Official documentation of sqlalchqmy ORM says about `reconstructor` decorator:

> Designates a method as the “reconstructor”, an `__init__`-like method that will be called by the ORM after the instance has been loaded from the database or otherwise reconstituted.

From this description I suppose that `init_on_load` should be called after re-fetch too, but it is'nt happened.

Is this bug or by-design behavior? And how should I proceed if it's normal behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation:

> [`reconstructor()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html#sqlalchemy.orm.reconstructor) is a shortcut into a larger system of “instance level” events, which can be subscribed to using the event API - see [`InstanceEvents`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents) for the full API description of these events.

In essence `reconstructor()` is a shortcut to [`InstanceEvents.load`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load):

> Receive an object instance after it has been created via `__new__`, and after initial attribute population has occurred.
>   ...
>   This typically occurs when the instance is created based on incoming result rows, and **is only called once for that instance’s lifetime**.

When you [commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit) or rollback the default is to just expire all ORM controlled attributes of the instances found in the session. The instances themselves stay alive. When you refetch a row that matches an instance found in the session, it is [refreshed](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.refresh). An example:

```
In [2]: from sqlalchemy.events import event

In [3]: class Foo(Base):
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   ...:     value = Column(Unicode)
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'foo'
   ...:
```

Add event listeners so we can track what is going on

```
In [5]: @event.listens_for(Foo, 'load')
   ...: def foo_load(target, context):
   ...:     print('Foo load')
   ...:     

In [6]: @event.listens_for(Foo, 'refresh')
   ...: def foo_load(target, context, attrs):
   ...:     print('Foo refresh')
   ...:     

In [7]: session.add(Foo(value='test'))

In [8]: session.commit()
```

Foo instance is constructed

```
In [9]: foo = session.query(Foo).first()
Foo load

In [10]: session.rollback()
```

The now expired instance found in the session is refreshed and returned

```
In [11]: foo2 = session.query(Foo).first()
Foo refresh
```

Both names are bound to the same instance

```
In [12]: foo is foo2
Out[12]: True

In [13]: session.rollback()
```

Attribute access on an expired instance causes just a refresh

```
In [14]: foo.value
Foo refresh
Out[14]: 'test'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed response! Apparently I had to dig deeper into the documentation